# Xcode shows up to 400% CPU Usage - but iPhone is only 2-core

Tags: objective-c, xcode

The following shows a screenshot of the Xcode CPU Report indicating that my application (while number crunching) is maxing-out one of the CPUs:

[image: CPU at 100]

The above shows a maximum of 400%. However the iPhone has a 2-core CPU, so I am wondering why the gauge doesn't go to 200% instead?

Furthermore, by using concurrency and splitting my number crunching across multiple threads I can max out at 400%, however my algorithm only runs twice as fast. Again, indicating that the work is divided across 2 CPU Cores.

Does anyone know why Xcode shows 400% and how this relates to the physical hardware?

Comment: I suspect a bug but a crazy idea: GCD is managing to use the GPU for some of your mandlebrot code.

Comment: maybe some sort of "hyper threading" nonsense, like 4 virtual cores but only 2 physical ones?

Comment: are you running on simulator?

Comment: @iHulk good point, yes this is the simulator.

Comment: in simulator it shows the processor of your mac and which, i guess, is a quadcore processor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are testing in a simulator then it shows reports on the basis of your MAC's processor that's why it is showing 400% ( for a quad-core processor).

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone has only 2 cores (although some iPads have more). The Mac running the simulator apparently has four, or two plus hyper threading.